# DataTable and pivot table and filters

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, pivot

I have a DataTable like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
  ,[NameMachine]
  ,[Reparation]
  ,[Substitution]
  ,[DataIn]
  ,[DataOut]
  ,[Operator]
  ,[TypeOperation]
  ,[Note]
  ,[Department] FROM [Man].[dbo].[Sheets]
```

I have to filter it, so I added this perameters:

```
SELECT ID, NameMachine, Reparation, Substitution, DataIn, DataOut, Operator, TypeOperation, Note, Department FROM dbo.Sheets WHERE Department = @Department AND year(DataIn) = @Year AND Operator =@Operator
```

Now, I have my filtered DataTable... But Here is the question:
How can i make a pivot like this?

```
SELECT NameMachine, Operator, Department, [1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10] + [11] + [12] AS Tot, [1] AS Gen, [2] AS Feb, [3] AS Mar, [4] AS Apr, [5] AS Mag, [6] AS Giu, [7] AS Lug, [8] AS Ago, [9] AS Sett, [10] AS Ott, [11] AS Nov, [12] AS Dic
FROM (SELECT ID, NameMachine, datepart(month, DataInizio) AS Month, Operator, Department FROM Sheets) 
m PIVOT (count(ID) FOR Month IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])) pvt
```

I don't know hot to make a query like that in my filtered dataTable... How can I query a DataTable?

Thank you for any suggestion...

Comment: What problems do you encounter with your querry? Do you just want to filter the inner select statement?

Comment: Would you like to do this in your database in a stored procedure or script using sql? or in a c# application using linq?

Comment: I want to Filter the table first, then make the pivot... But I don't know how...

Comment: It's the same for me, I have the Db in a SQL Server, and a c# program that use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT NameMachine, Operator, Department, [1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10] + [11] + [12] AS Tot, [1] AS Gen, [2] AS Feb, [3] AS Mar, [4] AS Apr, [5] AS Mag, [6] AS Giu, [7] AS Lug, [8] AS Ago, [9] AS Sett, [10] AS Ott, [11] AS Nov, [12] AS Dic
FROM (SELECT ID, NameMachine, datepart(month, DataInizio) AS Month, Operator, Department FROM Sheets WHERE Department = @Department AND year(DataIn) = @Year AND Operator =@Operator) 
m PIVOT (count(ID) FOR Month IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])) pvt
```

Comment: That's awesome!! Would you mind marking this as the answer? Thanks a bunch. @AlessandroSerbelloniMazzanti